# PSS for Camera2Basic is getting increased once you launched the app

Tags: android, performance, android-camera2

**Pre-Req**: I am using the Android Q version.

**Steps to reproduce:**

- Open the Camera2Basic app.
- Select any camera say Back JPEG (0)
- Keep the app running.
- On the device collect PSS for this app. Something like this.

  - target:/ # procrank | grep -i camera2

    5455 5381720K 219916K **111828K** 104916K com.android.example.camera2.basic
  - target:/ # procrank | grep -i camera2

    5455 5414488K 230008K **121916K** 115000K com.android.example.camera2.basic
  - procrank | grep -i camera2

    5455 5815896K 411812K **303704K** 296772K com.android.example.camera2.basic

You will notice that the PSS of this app is increasing continuously till 900 MB and after 5-6 min it will come down to 200 MB. Which is not good for Low mem targets.

I did some investigation (collected pmaps data) and found that the Android Native heap is increasing (increase in PSS seems to be due to “anon:libc_malloc”).

Please help with how to handle this.

Comment: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/183538881 has some discussion on this.